# Nest js promise interceptor

Tags: rxjs, nestjs, prisma2

Is there a way for me to wrap a request in nest js inside a callback?

I'm trying to create a prisma transaction interceptor but the problem is that nest js interceptor requires an obserable as return type.

In order to achieve my goal I need to wrap my request in a callback like:

```
await prisma.$transaction(async p => {
    await requestToBeFinished()
})
```

But all nest js provides me is an observable like

```
  return next
     .handle()
     .pipe(
        tap(() => {console.log('After execution')}),
     );
```

Is there a solution to this?
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you run the promise as an observable? The `from` operator from rxjs turns promises into observables

Comment: Can you give me an example? I need to have access to the `prisma` variable